# Add a logo above Bootstrap Nav bar

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am experimenting with Twitter Bootstrap using this [bootstrap example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/justified-nav.html)

I would like to replace the text logo (Project Name) with a PNG graphic and cant seem to get it done using this code:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="masthead">
    <h3 class="muted">Bull</h3>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.navbar -->
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That code has no image tag. Why would you expect it to display an image?

Comment: just learning, sorry for basic question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `<div class="masthead">` you have `<h3 class="muted">` containing the "Project Name" text.

Get rid of the `<h3>` and replace it with:

`<img src="foo.png" alt="" />`

(Of course you may want to put a `<figure>` or `<h1>` around your image, but it should be as simple as above)

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Sorry for such basic question, just learning.

Comment: Thank you again, I tried Google but must have been asking the wrong question.